# How to make a plugin for Kinetic.js ?(Edited)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Re posting the question again.
I didn't explain the question properly before so sorry about that.

Hope this will make up for it
I am planning to make a plugin for Kineticjs.
Now I'm not an expert at this so need some help.

I saw few examples online but they didn't help much.
Some Jquery tutorias that use the DOM elements and you can write your function to alter the behaviour or add functionality and all.

Like for making a jquery plugin we can do something like:

```
       (function($) {
             $.fn.nameofthefunction = function() {
           // Add plugin code here
               here I can manipulate dom elements and all..
             };
       })(jQuery);
```

What I need is to use inbuilt functions of kinetic.js make a plugin accordingly..
Kinetic.js is a HTML5 canvas library.
SO if I do something like

```
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({ 
    x: 325 - 45,
    y: 145 - 83,
    image: beeObj,          
    draggable: true,       
});
```

here "draggable:true" makes the image draggable

here is one example that is making the image resizable:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

I want to make a plugin using this example so that the user can just do something like resize:true or image.resize();
and the image/shape becomes resizable.

Hope I'm able to explain myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm i guess what you want to do , is to have options for your plugin .. that is achieved by

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.plguinname = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
          draggable: true ,
          other_optuion : 'value'
        }, options);
....
```

now when some body call your plugin he will pass some options if he like , other wise the plugin will use the default options (eg `other_optuion` will be `'value'`)
like so

```
$('.selector').plguinname({
draggable: true ,
other_optuion : 'some other value'
})
```

i guess you should read more about jquery plugin development..
one place i would recommend is youtube ;) for fast learning

Comment: But the thing is..It's still selecting an element from DOM ..eg. selector..What I want is to use an element generate by kinetic.js Like an image generated by the library.and then manipulate it .. I'm not able to explain myself..Will try something out and then post the code..

Comment: Your question was clearly asking for how to make a plugin and make it have the same functionality as the htm5 library your describing .. So please make sure to be clear on what you want next time , regarding what you want , you can select the element using $(element).ready , and then do what ever you want after it